# Case insensitive search function in C#

Tags: c#, regex, search, datagridview

I'd like to create a search function on my `DataGridView`, behind a button click event. To do that, I used the following source code:

```
chargerDataGrid();
dg_logiciel.ClearSelection();

string search = txtbox_recherche.Text;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dg_logiciel.Rows)
{
    if (!dgvr.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(search))
    {
        dgvr.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

It's working but I'd like to compare my two strings ignoring case. To do that, I've tried this code:

```
chargerDataGrid();
dg_logiciel.ClearSelection();

string search = txtbox_recherche.Text;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg_logiciel.Rows)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (!pattern.IsMatch(search))
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Which does not work at all. Am I using badly the `Regex` class or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, .NET lacks a `string.Contains(string, StringComparison)` function overload.

But you can easily add such an extension function to your project, as we have a suitable `IndexOf` overload:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparison)
    {
        return str.IndexOf(value, comparison) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Then simply use:

```
if (!dgvr.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

or use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` depending of your needs.

---

As for your regex attempt, it's plainly unnecessary to go to such lengths for that, but your attempt fails because of a combination of the following reasons:

- You inverted the value you search for and the string you search in. You'd have to build your regex instance with the `search` string as the pattern.
- Speaking of which, you should have escaped the search value. If it contains any regex metacharacters the pattern will be invalid. You could have used `Regex.Escape` for this purpose.

So, the following *would have worked*, but is **not** the proper way to do the job:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), Regex.Escape(search), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your answer what is the meaning of the following parameter and how will it work?

```
this string str
```

I mean how will `this` and static coexist

Comment: Just read about extension methods. And this post should be a comment to answer. Delete this as soon as possible.